# mysql .my.cnf not reading credentials properly?

Tags: mysql

I can connect to mysql using the following line:

```
mysql -u myusername -p
(enters password into terminal)
>>>Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>>>Your MySQL connection id is 51
>>>Server version: 5.6.10-log Source distribution
```

Here is my .my.cnf in my home directory (not /etc/my.cnf):

```
[client]
user = myusername
password = mypassword
host = localhost
```

There also appears to be a client section in my /etc/my.cnf:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port     = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

However when I just type "mysql" into the terminal, I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What is wrong with my my.cnf?

ALso, it has nothing to do with anon user as mentioned here: [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1)

Here is the result of a suggested query:

```
>>>mysql --print-defaults
>>>mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
>>>--port=3306 --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --no-auto-rehash --user=myusername --password=mypassword --host=localhost
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix your password & host config?

Comment: this is the .my.cnf file in my home directory, not the file in /etc/my.cnf. Should this stuff be in that one?

Comment: No, but if you get a message like `'myusername'@'mypassword'`, it seems like you have entered your password after `host=`, and probably your host after `password=`. if should be `'myusername'@'localhost'`...

Comment: oh sorry that was just an error in my question

Comment: Aight, then it should work AFAIK... What happens if you run `mysql --defaults-file=/your/home/dir/.my.cnf`, still the same? And what happens if you include the `socket` config in your own file?

Comment: same error when pointing to the file. Will try to remove all that stuff in /etc and see what happens.

Comment: nope commenting out the section in /etc/my.cnf did not work

Comment: Did you add the `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` to your `.my.cnf`, and is that indeed the socket of your server? Also, the output of `mysql --print-defaults` might shed some light on it..

Comment: yes I tried moving all that over to .my.cnf but to no avail

Comment: Well, `mysql --print-defaults` is my final hope then, let's see what it says..

Comment: Is the space between `--`  & `host` a copy/paste error, or really there?

Comment: OK, if that's not it... I blame invisible stray characters _somewhere_ (or a wrong password). Either examine it in a hex editor, or dump the file, type it in again, does that work?

Comment: Hm, one final guess came to me: if there are come characters like `=` & others in your password... you need to _quote_ the password, does that help?

Comment: That was it! My passwords are randomly generated and contain lots of non a-z0-9 characters, so quoting it in mysql solved the problem.  Please post that as an actual answer so I can accept it and give you my 50 rep points.

Comment: Ah, nice ;) I'll add that as an answer (with the rest of possible troubleshoots as well).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @Wrikken said in the comments, it will work if you quote your password and the password contains characters such as `=` or `;`.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you are missing the quotes around the password.

```
[client]
user = myusername
password = "mypassword"
host = localhost
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Search for "Here is a typical user option file:" and see the example they state in there.

Comment: Yes this was Wrikken's answer in the comments back in Oct, and that worked. (Andy later posted the exact same thing)